# One-time CSS expressions

Tags: javascript, css, css-expressions

This CSS expression

```
P {
   background-color: expression((new Date()).getHours()%2 ? "#B8D4FF" : "#F08A00");
}
```

can be called thousands of times

but this approach, means

```
<style>
P {
   background-color:expression(altBgColor(this));
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function altBgColor(elem) {
    elem.style.background = new Date()).getHours()%2 ? "#B8D4FF" : "#F08A00";
}
</script>
```

means it won't. Why?

Comment: Who cares? Just don't use CSS expressions at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you expect to happen?

The very first time your dynamic expression is called it *overwrites* the background property which contained that expression.

Comment: But why is one version called up to thousands of times, the other not.  Source of this exampe is Steve Sounders, High Performance Web Sites.

Comment: because once the property has been overwritten the dynamic expression no longer exists, so it's never re-invoked.

Comment: Are you saying the property is obly overwritten once in the second approach, whereas in the first it is not really ever overwritten but constantly set?

Answer (score 1):

Change `<style>` to `<script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function altBgColor(elem) {
         elem.style.background = new Date().getHours()%2 ? "#B8D4FF" : "#F08A00";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Done. But your commment isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

"For scripting, a dynamic property can be any legal JScript or Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript) statement." says [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634.aspx). JScript is NOT JavaScript. Also, a good thing is trying to stay away from CSS expressions altogether :)